# Where can I buy historic raw recording of an exchange

Tags: market-data, feed

Say I want to buy historically recorded raw feed from an European exchange (say LSE).
Is there a vendor that would sell me this data ?

EDIT: By raw feed I mean the order by order feed (or equivalent) that would enable me to build the entire book at any point in day.

Cheers

Comment: What is wrong with the vendors you found when you searched? You did search, didn't you? ;)

Comment: Hi Joshua, I did not find any, I want the historical order by order feed right ?

Comment: I have no idea what you want. "Raw feed" is vague. Do you want quotes, trades, both? If you want quotes, do you want top-of-book, depth (how much?), etc?

Comment: I edited my OP .

Comment: Presumably "raw feed" means the depth of book data one would consume if co-located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy data directly from every exchange I've looked at. LSE sells data as well [right here on their webpage](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/products-and-services/reference-data/reference-data.htm)

Sounds like you're looking for their [Trade Data](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/products-and-services/reference-data/trade/trade-data.htm) product which includes order book information: "Provides an end-of-day download file of the day's Order Book activity, including all trades, orders and deletions in Order Book securities since October 1997..."

Comment: I'll have a look at that, for some reason I heard before the exchange could not deliver it!!! thanks

Comment: Is the resolution of the time stamps provided by the exchanges (such as LSE using the link above)  sufficient to reconstruct the actual chronological sequence of orders/trades? I am referring to the presence of HFT that pushes the needed resolution to fractions of  milliseconds.